# cpp: permit base member access only via derived by consumer

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, private-members

I have an application where Base is a factory class for objects that shall be created differently depending on a template pair. However, only very particular (countable infinite) number of template pairs make sense. For each of sensible pair, I have a (sometimes) templated Derived Factory class. The use of Base Factory is error prone due to the need for feasible correct choice of the template pair.

My question is: How can I prevent a consumer from using the Base Factory directly?

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Base{
  Base()=delete;
public:
  // many public static routines
  T1 static foo(){ return 1; }
  T2 static bar(){ return 2; }
};

template<typename T1>
class Derived: public Base<T1,float>{
  // hopefully very little code, or none at all, as of now.
};

int main(){ // main is the consumer
  Base<int,float>::foo(); // prevent
  Derived<int>   ::foo(); // permit
}
```

I want the compiler to reject/thow/err the line with comment "prevent" in main. I want Base<..>::foo and Base<..>::bar not directly accessible by a consumer unless via access through Derived<..>. I had hoped that the `virtual` concept could be used for that purpose; however it does not transfer naturally from the non-static to the static case.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, because you should not edit your question to invalidate exitsing answer(s).

Comment: @wohlstad I don't think that edit invalidates your answer. It says "it would be nice if...", but it isn't a strict requirement. In my opinion there was no need to roll it back.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica from the OP's comment in my answer below I understood it is actually important for the OP. But thinking again I agree the rollback might have been not needed. Feel free to rollback to the 2nd version if you think it gives the question more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the `foo` method `protected`, and expose it via the `Derived` class with a `public` `using` statement:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Base {
    Base() = delete;
protected:
    T1 static foo() { return 1; }
    T2 static bar() { return 2; }
};

template<typename T1>
class Derived : public Base<T1, float> {
public:
    using Base<T1, float>::foo;
};

int main() { // main is the consumer
    Base<int, float>::foo(); // prevent
    Derived<int>   ::foo(); // permit
}
```

[Live demo - Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dsEz98dbM)

Comment: Thank you. That is already neat. Yet a bit picky, the implementation of Derived would need to implement one line for each routine in Base. Is there a solution that avoids this?, so that I can add arbitrarily many functions to Base without each time incrementing the code of Derived?

Comment: I am not aware of such option.

Comment: Note that you don't have to necessarily modify all your derived classes right away. You can simply make the methods protected in `Base` and then expose only the ones you actually use in any of your defived classes (the compiler can help identifying all these places).

Comment: Well (explicit) correctness should be IMO more important than a little bit of typing. You But it also using inheritance to just manage visibility seems to me like a misuse of inheritance.